# Would anyone know how to do an algorithm iteratively (using while) for the following definition?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, while-loop

[image]

(Note: "en otro caso" means in another case; click in "enter image descriptioon here to view de image")

I want to make an iterative algorithm from the definition they have given me. I have it done with memory recursion, I share it if it helps:

```
public static Integer eje4ConMemoria(Integer d1, Integer d2, Map<Tuple2<Integer, Integer>, Integer> memoria) {
    Integer result = null;
    Integer a = d1;
    Integer b = d2;
    Tuple2<Integer, Integer> t = Tuple.create(a, b);
    if (memoria.containsKey(t)) {
        result = memoria.get(t);
    } else if (a < 2 && b < 2) {
        result = a + b * b;
        memoria.put(t, result);
    } else if (a < 2 || b < 2) {
        result = a * a + b;
        memoria.put(t, result);
    } else {
        result = eje4ConMemoria(a / 2, b - 1, memoria) + eje4ConMemoria(a / 3, b - 2, memoria)
                + eje4ConMemoria(a - 2, b / 4, memoria);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: And have you started converting it to work iteratively? Where is the problem?

Comment: Why do you want that?

Comment: (There is code duplication in your implementation. Not catastrophic in and of itself, but it veils an omission detrimental to execution time. Or, much worse, exaggerates performance benefits of a non-impeded iterative implementation.)

Answer (score -2):

A simple list system should work here. The end result, if you expand any given `g(a, b)`, is simply a long list of 'things to add together'. It'll be a gigantic chain of simple values (e.g. `g(6, 2)` becomes `g(3, 1) + g(2, 0) + g(4, 0.5)` and that becomes `(6^2 + 2) + (2 + 0) + (4^2 + 0.5)`.

Thus, you can reconstrue the job as generating a list of terms that still need processing, plus keeping a count going for 'processed out' nodes.

NB: Some notes first; `Integer` is incorrect, use `int`. I have no idea why you are passing in a 'map of tuple2', `Tuple2` is silly; it's not idiomatic at all, nobody* in the java community writes code like this.

NB2: You are doing integer division, i.e. you're saying that `3 divided by 2 is 1`, not 1.5. Presumably that's intentional. If it is not, replace *ALL* occurences of `int` with `double`.

```
public static int eje4(int a, int b) {
    class Node {
        final int a, b;
        Node(int a, int b) { this.a = a; this.b = b; }
    }

    Queue<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<>();
    queue.push(new Node(a, b));

    int result = 0;
    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        Node n = queue.pop();
        if (n.a < 2 && n.b < 2) {
            result += (n.a + n.b * n.b);
            continue;
        }
        if (n.a < 2 || n.b < 2) {
            result += (n.a * n.a + n.b);
            continue;
        }
        
        queue.push(new Node(n.a / 2, n.b - 1));
        queue.push(new Node(n.a / 3, n.b - 2));
        queue.push(new Node(n.a - 2, n.b / 4));
    }
    return result;
}
```

*) Some clowns do, like vavr, which is cool, but it's not what the vast majority of java code out there is like. If you love that sort of thing, scala will be more to your liking.

Comment: Looks like you forgot about the memoization. Why is `Integer` "incorrect"?

Comment: (`Node` is a budding `Tuple2`.)

Comment: @greybeard but non-global and descriptive.

Comment: @superbrain The question as posed doesn't ask about memoization.

Comment: Thanks @rzwitserloot !!!, and i don't know why I should use int. Finally pls you don't use words like clowns.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It doesn't explicitly ask for it, at least not clearly, but their code uses it, and rightly so, as that helps a lot.